# cURL to PHP Translation Issues

Tags: php, curl

Okay...newbie question that I can't figure out.  Here's what the [Box.com documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#upload-a-file) says for uploading a file:

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST \
  -F attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"11446498"}}' \
  -F file=@myfile.jpg
```

I'm trying this in PHP:

```
$attributes='{"name":"tigers.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"4224475591"}}';
 $headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$prep_data = array('file'=>'data08.13.15.csv','attributes' => $attributes);
$post_data=  http_build_query($prep_data) . "\n";
$url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
var_dump($response);
```

I'm getting `string(0) ""` back for my `var_dump($response);`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying that it is multipart form data. Not sure if you have other issues as well. But here is some working code you can change to meet your needs:

```
<?php
    // ENTER YOUR DEVELOPER TOKEN
    $token = "ekdfokeEdfdfkosdkoqwekof93kofsdfkosodSqd";

    $url = "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content";
    if (isset($_POST['btnUpload'])) {
        $file_upload = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $json = json_encode(array(
                                'name' => $_FILES['file']['name'], 
                                'parent' => array('id' => 0)
                            ));
        $fields = array(
                      'attributes' => $json,
                      'file'=>new CurlFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['type'],$_FILES['file']['name'])
                  );

        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer '.$token, 
                'Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
            ));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response = $e->getMessage();
        }

        print_r($response);
    }

?>

<form method="post" name="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload file to Box
        <input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>
    </label>
    <input name="btnUpload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

http://liljosh.com/uploading-files-to-box-content-api-v2/